# what is the logic to wait for workflow END_time?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have created one workflow 1] WF_OFSLL_WVR_STTS_CHK for checking the duration of another workflow that is 2]  WF_OFSLL_WVR_MASTER_LOAD to check the how much time it has taken to complete the workflow. i scheduled both workflow at 3 am. so , i want logic for when 2 workflow start it should wait for END_TIME and once it complete it should have to calculate the duration of master load workflow START and END Time.

Answer (score 0):

1. How about command task with file touch at the start of
   WF_OFSLL_WVR_MASTER_LOAD and another command task with file touch as
   last step? You can easily compare the timestamps then?
2. Or checking the logs?
3. Or checking the repository metadata?

Anyhow I cannot find any justification for using another workflow for this purpose.